# Parsing a json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have this json file which has the image name(medical images-around 7500) and its corresponding medical reports.
It is of the format:

```
{"IMAGE_NAME1.png": "MEDICAL_REPORT1_IN_TEXT", "IMAGE_NAME2.png": "MEDICAL_REPORT2_IN_TEXT", ...and so on for all images ...}
```

What I want is all the image names in the JSON file so that I can take all the images(From a database of images which is a super set of the image names in the JSON file) and make its own folder. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I don't exactly get your question since I am an inexperienced coder. But I think the link to the JSON file can help answer your question: https://github.com/ZexinYan/Medical-Report-Generation/blob/master/data/new_data/captions.json

Comment: Checkout json.load() which takes a json file and transforms it to a Python object. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: There is a native json package to help with this. It will provide a simple dictionary which can easily be handled for the task you ask for

Comment: I used the json.load to get a dictionary but wasn't able to deal with the task of extracting the image names further. Can you please help me with that and I am extremely sorry for being an absolute noob.  import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('captions.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)                      The code I have used till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the json library.  I haven't tested this, but I am pretty confident it will work.

```
import json

with open("path/to/json.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
```

to get image names from what you described the data to look like.

```
image_names = list(json_data.keys())
```

Comment: Hey just another query, when I run the above code and print out the length of image_names I get 7430. But when I open the JSON file with notepad++ and try to find out the number of search results for CXR(as all the image names start with this) I get 7432. So where is this difference of two coming from?

Comment: OK never mind maybe the captions had cxr in them so I tried searching for cxr0, cxr1, cxr2, cxr3 and so on and they all added up to 7430. So that is great.